# VSCode extension: add decorator outside text area

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to visualise where comments should end, but I didn't find a great solution to add decorators outside the text area:

```js
const decoration = {
    range: new vscode.Range(i, start + maxCommentLineLength, i, start + maxCommentLineLength),
    renderOptions: {
        after: {
            contentText: "",
            border: style,
            margin: `0 0 0 ${emPerChar * Math.max(0, start + maxCommentLineLength - line.length)}em` // Using margin is a hack
        }
    },
    rangeBehavior: vscode.DecorationRangeBehavior.ClosedClosed
};
```

This works almost, but rounding errors can cause issues: [bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGZkN.png)

Here's the full code: https://github.com/Nineteendo/comment-rulers/blob/main/src/extension.ts

Any ideas how to improve this?